# getopt() in C not working correctly after if statement

Tags: c, argv, getopt, argc

I would like to implement a copy of the Linux head commmand. If the user types in `./cprogram head -(option here)` I would like for the option to appear but for some reason my code never enters the options `switch` statement. For example the command line code `./cprogram head -n` never enters the `case 'n':` statement. The code was working before the `if` statement to check if the `argv[1]` is `"head"`.

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int b;
    int c;
    int nflag = 0;
    int Vflag = 0;
    int hflag = 0;
    int eflag = 0;
    int oflag = 0;
    char str[] = "head";
    if (strcmp(argv[1], str) == 0) {
        while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "nVheo")) != -1) {
            switch (c) {
              case 'n':
                if (nflag||Vflag||hflag||eflag||oflag) {
                    printf("only one option\n");
                    exit(1);
                } else {
                    nflag++;
                    printf("n option\n");
                }
                break;
              case 'V':
                if (nflag||Vflag||hflag||eflag||oflag) {
                    printf("only one option\n");
                    exit(1);
                } else {
                    Vflag++;
                }
                break;
              case 'h':
                if (nflag||Vflag||hflag||eflag||oflag) {
                    printf("only one option\n");
                    exit(1);
                } else {
                    hflag++;
                }
                break;
              case 'e':
                if (nflag||Vflag||hflag||eflag||oflag) {
                    printf("only one option\n");
                    exit(1);
                } else {
                    eflag++;
                }
                break;
              case 'o':
                if (nflag||Vflag||hflag||eflag||oflag) {
                    printf("only one option\n");
                    exit(1);
                } else {
                    oflag++;
                }
                break;
              default:
                printf("invalid options\n");
                abort();
            }
        } 
    } else {
    }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate an expert eye to have a look and spot what I'm missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Under Linux/Ubuntu and compiled with gcc, your program works correctly. How do you build it and run it ?

Comment: The problem is that `head` is not a valid option, so `getopt` immediately returns -1.

Comment: `if(nflag||Vflag||hflag||eflag||oflag){` it would be easier to write that once after the loop. Not in each case.

Comment: You want to call `getopt` with `argv + 1` since  `getopt` will assume that options start at the next argument and that options should precede non-options.

Comment: `argc` also needs to be adjusted to `argc - 1`.

Comment: im using cgwin64 windows 7 @RachidK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `getopt()` to skip `argv[1]` and parse options from the next element, you should set `optind` before calling `getopt()`:

```
optind = 2;
```

Also note that you should also check if `argc > 1` before comparing `argv[1]` with `"head"`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int b;
    int c;
    int nflag = 0;
    int Vflag = 0;
    int hflag = 0;
    int eflag = 0;
    int oflag = 0;
    char str[] = "head";

    if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], str) == 0) {
        optind = 2;  // skip argv[1]
        while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "nVheo")) != -1) {
            if (nflag | Vflag | hflag | eflag | oflag) {
                fprintf(stderr, "only one option\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            switch (c) {
              case 'n':
                nflag++;
                printf("n option\n");
                break;
              case 'V':
                Vflag++;
                break;
              case 'h':
                hflag++;
                break;
              case 'e':
                eflag++;
                break;
              case 'o':
                oflag++;
                break;
              default:
                fprintf(stderr, "invalid option `%c'\n", c);
                abort();
            }
        } 
        /* perform head on files starting at argv[optind] */
    } else {
        /* test some other command */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Combining all the suggestions in the top comments:

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int b;
    int c;
    int nflag = 0;
    int Vflag = 0;
    int hflag = 0;
    int eflag = 0;
    int oflag = 0;
    char str[] = "head";

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("not enough arguments\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (strcmp(argv[1], str) != 0) {
        printf("1st argument is not '%s'\n",str);
        exit(1);
    }

    // skip over the [matched] str
    --argc;
    ++argv;

    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "nVheo")) != -1) {
        if (nflag || Vflag || hflag || eflag || oflag) {
            printf("only one option\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        switch (c) {
        case 'n':
            nflag++;
            printf("n option\n");
            break;

        case 'V':
            Vflag++;
            break;

        case 'h':
            hflag++;
            break;

        case 'e':
            eflag++;
            break;

        case 'o':
            oflag++;
            break;

        default:
            printf("invalid options\n");
            abort();
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

To test, invoke with these [a shell script `test`]:

```
./myprogram
./myprogram foo
./myprogram head
./myprogram head -n
./myprogram head -n -n
```

---

Here is the `sh -x ./test` output:

```
+ ./myprogram
not enough arguments
+ ./myprogram foo
1st argument is not 'head'
+ ./myprogram head
+ ./myprogram head -n
n option
+ ./myprogram head -n -n
n option
only one option
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The above code is a bit of a "cheat". It eliminates the `str` (e.g. `"head"`) by moving it into `argv[0]` which is the program name (e.g. `./myprogram`). The actual program name gets trashed.

A more correct way is to "slide" `argv` to eliminate the string and *preserve* the program name:

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int b;
    int c;
    int nflag = 0;
    int Vflag = 0;
    int hflag = 0;
    int eflag = 0;
    int oflag = 0;
    char str[] = "head";

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("not enough arguments\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (strcmp(argv[1], str) != 0) {
        printf("1st argument is not '%s'\n",str);
        exit(1);
    }

    // skip over the [matched] str
    for (int avidx = 1;  avidx < argc;  ++avidx)
        argv[avidx] = argv[avidx + 1];
    --argc;

    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "nVheo")) != -1) {
        if (nflag || Vflag || hflag || eflag || oflag) {
            printf("only one option\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        switch (c) {
        case 'n':
            nflag++;
            printf("n option\n");
            break;

        case 'V':
            Vflag++;
            break;

        case 'h':
            hflag++;
            break;

        case 'e':
            eflag++;
            break;

        case 'o':
            oflag++;
            break;

        default:
            printf("invalid options\n");
            abort();
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a simpler way to skip `argv[1]`: set `optind = 2` before calling `getopt()`.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks. Didn't know that because I never use `getopt` et. al. [preferring to roll my own in most cases]. Or, calling something else like `MPI_Init`